# Populating the fields based on bean property selection

Tags: jquery, spring

I have a list of beans(Employees) and want to display the names(Employee.userName) in the drop down. Once user selects one userName, the employee details such as Employee.firstName,lastName,address,email...should be populated below the drop down.I am using spring tags in the form. And getting the list by spring modelAttribute. Can anyone please help me in this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Controller put employee list to model

```
ModelAndView mov = new ModelAndView("yourView");

ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("xmlWithYourBean.xml");
List<Employee> employeeList = (List<Employee>) appContext.getBean("helloWorld");

mov.addObject( "employeeList", employeeList );
```

And in view do something like this:

```
<select>
<c:forEach items="${employeeList}" var="employee">
<option>${employee.firstName}<option>       
 </c:forEach>
 </select>
```

If you want show description by person name, create method in your controller `getPersonDescription` and redirect location or use ajax

```
<script>
    function getValue() {
        var e = document.getElementById("myselect");
        var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
        return strUser;
    }
</script>

<select id="myselect" 
 onchange="document.location.href = 'http://localhost:8080/yourProjet/getPersonDescription?username=' + getValue();" >
```

Comment: Thanks Kris for the response. But Initially i am able display the list of names in the drop down. But once i select a name from the drop down i want to populate other properties of the bean.

Comment: Is there any way to auto populate the bean properties based on selection? Thanks.

Comment: you can create in html divs with css: 'display:none' for all person and replace them when user change selected item, but i think it's not good solution